# how to enable power saving for a wireless usb mouse

Tags: wireless, usb, mouse, power-management

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.6. I use a wireless mouse, it consumes much power so I need to replace new battery every month. I noticed that mouse never sleeps.

How can I enable power saving feature for only wireless mouse?

Comment: you need to look for support from Vendor I guess..

Comment: "I need to replace new battery every month" => I strongly suggest that you invest in some rechargeable batteries...